# How to download stable version of wxPython?

Tags: software-installation, wxpython

How to download the stable version of wxPython for Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7 version?

Comment: Is it a stable version ? I am already using `python-wxgtk3.0 is already the newest version (3.0.2.0+dfsg-1build1)` . But I don't know whether it's stable version or not.

Answer (score 1):

To install the stable version of wxPython for Python 2.7 from the default Ubuntu repositories, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-wxtools  # tools from the wxPython distribution
```

wxPython 4.0.1 has been released. To get the GTK3 wxPython builds for Ubuntu 16.04 you can use a pip command like this:

```
sudo apt install python-pip  
sudo pip install -U \
    -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 \
    wxPython
```

Comment: I am unable to install. Getting  `E: Unable to locate package python-wxtools`

Comment: @Dinesh The package [python-wxtools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-wxtools) is in the Universe repository. Can you check you have [enabled it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)?

Comment: After you have enabled the universe repository, the command `apt policy python-wxtools` should show that python-wxtools Candidate: 3.0.2.0+dfsg-1build1 is available to be installed.